# GeoServer ImageMosaic PostGIS index update

Tags: postgis, geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

I use GeoServer where I created an ImageMosaic storage following this [manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_time-elevationseries.html).
When I create a new datastore, all `*.tif` files are indexed into the DB (PostgreSQL with PostGIS). How can I create new index entry in the DB, when I put new geotiff into my data folder, or reindex all geotiff files in the DB?

My config files:

datastore.properties:

```
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
host=localhost
port=5432
database=GeoServerRaster
schema=public
user=geoserver
passwd=*******
Loose\ bbox=true
Estimated\ extends=false
validate\ connections=true
Connection\ timeout=10
preparedStatements=true
```

indexer.properties:

```
Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion
ElevationAttribute=elevation
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date,elevation:Integer
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion),DoubleFileNameExtractorSPI[elevationregex](elevation)
```

timeregex.properties:

```
regex=[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z(\?!.\*[0-9]{8}T[0-9]{6}Z.\*)
```

elevationregex.properties:

```
regex=(?<=_)(\\d{1,5})(?=_)
```

files in directory:

```
tc_10000_20140807T033115Z.tif
tc_10000_20140807T040046Z.tif
tc_10000_20140807T043115Z.tif
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO the best way how to do it is via REST with the `curl` command.

To reindex the whole existing ImageMosaic, use something like the following command (remember to set correct username, password, workspace name, ImageMosaic store name and the path to the granules directory):

```
curl -v -u username:password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" \
 -d "file:///path/to/your/image/mosaic/directory/" \
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/YOUR_WORKSPACE/coveragestores/YOUR_IMAGEMOSAIC_STORE/external.imagemosaic"
```

This will delete all granules from the current index and then add existing files one by one. It is very time consuming.

I prefer adding a single granule (i.e. 1 raster file):

```
curl -v -u username:password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/plain" \
 -d "file:///path/to/your/image/mosaic/directory/and/your/granule.tiff" \
 "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/YOUR_WORKSPACE/coveragestores/YOUR_IMAGEMOSAIC_STORE/external.imagemosaic"
```

Both examples assume the raster files are already present at the specified location (that's specified by `external.imagemosaic` at the end of the URL).

More examples are in [the GeoServer docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/workspaces.html#updating-an-image-mosaic-contents).

Comment: Your link moved to http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/workspaces.html#updating-an-image-mosaic-contents or maybe http://docs.geoserver.org/api/#/1.0.0/coveragestores.yaml