# How can I extract time and elevation from this data?

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, raster-dataset

I download metadata from 
http://geoportale.lamma.rete.toscana.it/MapStore/public/ based on this tutorial
http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/en/accessing_multidim/rtx/wind_arrows.html and extract it to a folder, so there is some .tiff files in it.
then I opened my Geoserver 2.8.1 and on this path: Stores->add new Store-> ImageMosaic ( image mosaicking plugin) then choose the folder contains tiff files.
then in the layer configuration, dimension tab, I should see that the time and elevation attributes are enabled as it is mentioned in the tutorial but they are not and The following message appears next to each of the respective enable checkboxes:

Time

```
Cannot enable, no attribute of type Date found
```

Elevation

```
Cannot enable, no attribute of type Number found
```

I already saw this question [How to add time and elevation dimension attributes to Geoserver rasters?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170464/how-to-add-time-and-elevation-dimension-attributes-to-geoserver-rasters?newreg=f253729682984e5a998a4b2887111eb7) but that is not my case since I have not insert Geotiff Data into my Postgres or whatsoever.
I spend two days on solving this and read a lot about it with googling the issue.

Comment: I don't know much about geoserver, but it sounds like your data types may need some manipulation.  You also may want to see this question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/170464/how-to-add-time-and-elevation-dimension-attributes-to-geoserver-rasters

Comment: do your tiffs have time (and elevation) encoded in their names? did you set the indexer properties to extract that value?

Comment: @iant thanks for your comment, i now add indexer,datastore,elevation and time.properties like this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109885/geoserver-imagemosaic-postgis-index-update but when i clicked the save button this error happens: ` could not list layers for this store,an error occurred retrieving them: failed to create reader from file: [filepostion] and hits null

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @nmtoken the question is i cannot extract time and elevation from the data. thanks to iant i found that i should use properties files to extract them but when i include the properties files i faced the error i mentioned in the last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by installing geoserver 2.6.0 instead of 2.8.x and everything works fine, also, I should note that the database attribute name that is mentioned in the "datastore.properties" file must not exist in the postgres.